# What do you say when you don't know someone's gender?

Tags: grammatical-gender, personal-pronouns

For example, I want to refer to someone on the internet, but I don't know this person's gender. Which personal-pronoun do I use? (as article I mean he, she, it, etc)

Comment: You're talking about personal pronouns, not articles. As well, when you say that you don't know the person's gender, do you mean that you don't know what gender, masculine or feminine, they identify with; or do you mean that you don't know if they are male or female? If it's the latter, you're talking about their sex.

Comment: Thank you about the article/pronoun thing. About the gender/sex. Does that affect the answer? D:

Comment: @badroit Do I have to delete this question?

Comment: @ntrx, no, I guess it will be closed as a duplicate. No need to act on your side. And no, the gender/sex thing doesn't affect the answer. (I would have worded it as "gender" too.)

Comment: Yes, I think it's a duplicate. No worries @ntrx.

Comment: Please ignore @tylerharms' comment about sex and gender: they are are talking about how they presumably think English ought to be, not about how it currently is.

Comment: @ColinFine: What? What? English ought to represent the fact that sex and gender are different. If this question is asked about whether a person is transgendered, it is a lot different than if it is asked about whether a person with an ambiguous avatar is male or female. If I am in a trans chat room, and I want to know how to refer to someone who is a woman but may identify with men, it is completely fair to ask, "Which pronoun do I use to refer to someone on the internet when their gender isn't clear?" I was clarifying this point from a new user.

Comment: Gender neutral pronouns and the correctness of using 'they' to refer to a singular person was discussed on the Lexicon Valley podcast. http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley/2012/05/lexicon_valley_seeking_a_gender_neutral_alternative_to_he_and_she_.html

Comment: @tylerharms: _some_ English users distinguish between gender and sex, but the majority (I believe) do not, probably because most people never encounter a case where their extensional meanings differ. But in any case what English _ought_ to represent is inevitably a matter of opinion; what it _does_ represent is in principle an observable fact.

Comment: @ColinFine: I just can't support that rationale because there are people for whom the difference defines their identity. Men who would rather be called "she" and vice versa. I don't think that's the same discussion as the Gender Neutral Pronoun discussion that we've hashed out on this site.

Comment: @Tylerharms: I wasn't aware of that. But as you say, it's a different discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to use *they* in the singular sense. (Verbs are conjugated the same as they would be in the plural sense: "*are they joking?*", "*did they break anything?*".)

All the same, when the gender is not known, some authors prefer constructions like *(s)he*, *he/she*, *he or she*, *she or he*, etc., some prefer to stick with the masculine pronoun as default (*he*), others prefer to stick with the feminine pronoun for balance (*she*), some will alternate using *he* and *she* in their writing.

Answer (score 8):

When talking about a *hypothetical person*, "they" is quite established usage, although "he or she" is more formal.

> Someone posting a question should always clearly indicate the type of answer **they** want.

or

> Someone posting a question should always clearly indicate the type of answer **he or she** wants.

However, you can risk offending someone if you use "they" about that person in particular -- almost as much as if you guessed and used the wrong gender.  In that case, I would re-write the sentence to reuse the user name or to use other nouns:

> As @ntrx clearly states in the question...

or

> As the original poster clearly stated...

Comment: Have you encountered somebody being offended by being referred to as _they_ by somebody who didn't know their sex? I don't recall that I have. I have encountered people who got annoyed about **anybody** using _they_ to refer to one person in **any** circumstances, but that's different.

Comment: @ColinFine Fair argument.  I certainly can't cite any examples one way or the other.  But most of the time you can sidestep the issue, so I would recommend doing that if you can, just to avoid having your message lost in a debate on grammar.